# Connecting splitted dense layers in Neural Networks - Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I've seen that in `keras` I can use `tf.slpit` to split layers. My problem is that I don't understand how to do the connections between the "forked ways" that each layer must take.

Here is an image of an example I'm trying to do. It is basically an Input layer that splits into 2 sub-NN and then reunite in a layer before the output.

Diagram (thin black lines white poligons represent the wheight connections matrixes):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

After googling with better words (as **merge** neural networks) I found that Keras Functional API are the answer.

Helpful links:

- https://machinelearningmastery.com/keras-functional-api-deep-learning/
- https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-merge-two-different-models-in-keras

Example code from first link:

```
# Shared Input Layer
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate
# input layer
visible = Input(shape=(64,64,1))
# first feature extractor
conv1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(visible)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
flat1 = Flatten()(pool1)
# second feature extractor
conv2 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=8, activation='relu')(visible)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
flat2 = Flatten()(pool2)
# merge feature extractors
merge = concatenate([flat1, flat2])
# interpretation layer
hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(merge)
# prediction output
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden1)
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
# summarize layers
print(model.summary())
# plot graph
plot_model(model, to_file='shared_input_layer.png')
```